# jQuery - dynamic background for appended output from checkbox

Tags: jquery

How do I get each `tag` to take the background color of it's associated `checkbox`'s `data-color`?

Right now it changes the color of all tags.

```js
$("input").on("click", function(e) {
  var tagColor = $(this).attr("data-color");
  var tag = `<output class='tag'></output>`;
  if ($(this).is(".chk")) {
    $(".chks").empty();
    $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
      $(tag)
        .appendTo(".chks")
        .attr("data-tag", $(this).val())
        .css("background", tagColor)
        .val($(this).val());
    });
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.selections {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

output.tag {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 9px;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  padding: 0.9rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='selections'>
  <div class='tags chks'></div>
</div>
<div class="chkes">
  <label><input data-color="purple" value="one" type="checkbox" data-type='one' class="chk">One</label>
  <label><input data-color="orange" value="two" type="checkbox" data-type='two' class="chk">Two</label>
  <label><input data-color="brown" value="three" type="checkbox" data-type='three' class="chk">Three</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Following modified code should work

```js
$("input").on("click", function(e) {
  var container = $(".chks")
 
  var tag = `<output class='tag'></output>`;
  if ($(this).hasClass("chk")) {
    container.empty()
    $("input.chk:checked").each(function(index) {
      var tagColor = $(this).attr("data-color");
      $(tag)
        .appendTo(container)
        .attr("data-tag", $(this).val())
        .css("background", tagColor)
        .val($(this).val());
    });
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.selections {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

output.tag {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 9px;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  padding: 0.9rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='selections'>
  <div class='tags chks'></div>
</div>
<div class="chkes">
  <label><input data-color="purple" value="one" type="checkbox" data-type='one' class="chk">One</label>
  <label><input data-color="orange" value="two" type="checkbox" data-type='two' class="chk">Two</label>
  <label><input data-color="brown" value="three" type="checkbox" data-type='three' class="chk">Three</label>
</div>
```